# DateTime.ParseExact with custom format fails

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

Given is this date String `2021.328.2042.52` (Which comes from an external source)

Im using this format `yyyy.Mdd.Hmm.s`

Im also using it to create the DateTime too: `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.Mdd.Hmm.s")`

But somehow the date can't be parsed back with the following statement:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("2021.328.2042.52", "yyyy.Mdd.Hmm.s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var x);
```

Full test code:

```
var testDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.Mdd.Hmm.s");

DateTime.TryParseExact(testDate, "yyyy.Mdd.Hmm.s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var x);
```

Any answer is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried with yyyy.Mdd.HHmm.ss ? You're using two digit for hours and seconds

Comment: @PiGi78 its two digit because its 24h and 8PM is 20. But yes I tried that already. Same result

Comment: With `yyyy.MMdd.HHmm.s` format its work fine.

Comment: @Genusatplay I can't use MM neither can I use HH because leading zeros are removed from the string source. So I have to get the given format to work. I edited my question to clarify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use format with `M` or `H` you need separate data or use `MM` and `HH`

```
var testDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.M.dd.H.mm.s");
Console.WriteLine(testDate);

DateTime.TryParseExact(testDate, "yyyy.M.dd.H.mm.s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var x);
Console.WriteLine(x);
        
var testDate2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MMdd.HHmm.s");
Console.WriteLine(testDate2);

DateTime.TryParseExact(testDate2, "yyyy.MMdd.HHmm.s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var x2);
Console.WriteLine(x2);
```

Result:

```
    2021.3.28.20.31.36
    03/28/2021 20:31:36
    2021.0328.2031.36
    03/28/2021 20:31:36
```

**upd:** variant with adding leading zero

```
var testDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.Mdd.Hmm.s");

var data = testDate.Split('.');
if (data[1].Length != 4)
   data[1] = "0" + data[1];

if (data[2].Length != 4)
   data[2] = "0" + data[2];

var parsedTestDate = string.Join(".", data);
Console.WriteLine(parsedTestDate);

DateTime.TryParseExact(parsedTestDate, "yyyy.MMdd.HHmm.s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var x);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But why is this so? A day can never be 3 digits long because its between 1 and 31, so why is this causing a problem. Im really confused by this. Or can it be confused because if we have 124 (Month 1, day 24) it doesn't know which to pick?

Comment: That's right, he found month - `12` but not found day with `dd`

Comment: Thats interessting because. Well if it would be 3 digit. Just use the first for month always. If its four digit well its month and day together. Its weird, that this doesn't work if we would get with this logic. Because I have to use the given format.

Comment: you can parse your string date, if you add leading zero himself if length of group less then 4

Comment: Thats a good idea. I think this very specific format is just causing trouble probably will do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like can't really get `ParseExact` to work seamlessly, and massaging the input before passing it to `ParseExact` could make the code confusing.

We don't care about culture for this (there's no month abbreviations nor do we need to worry about day/month order or delimiters). So we're free to write out own algorithm. Here's how I would do it, which I think is pretty explicit:

```
var input = "2021.328.2042.52";
var segments = input.Split('.').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
var result = new DateTime
(
    year:   segments[0],
    month:  segments[1] / 100,
    day:    segments[1] % 100,
    hour:   segments[2] / 100,
    minute: segments[2] % 100,
    second: segments[3]
);
```